# keeping content from underneath the keyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I got a UIViewController and I have a UIScrollView with a few UITextFields inside. I got a piece of code from apple that seems to move the content from underneath the keyboard.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.firstResponder.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-10));
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

My UIScrollView is 320x416 because I have a navigation bar. Also my keyboard gets 44 more pixels because I'm adding a UIToolBar to it, so the code is not really working. I tried all kinds of configurations to solve two problems:

1. The last two fields are being covered by the UIToolBar + keyboard but only the last one triggers the UIScrollView movement.
2. Besides the UIScrollView is moving, the UITextField is still behind the keyboard due to the UIToolBar.

**UPDATE:** This works, but I'm pretty sure is wrong, and if is right, I don't know why, doesn't makes sense to me. Can someone fix / explain it?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height + 44.0f, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
   aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height + 44.0f;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.firstResponder.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-10.0f - 44.0f - 44.0f - 44.0f));
        [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**UPDATE1:** There is another bug, I have a previous button in the UIToolBar, if I tap the last text field, the scroll view goes up, If I move back to the first text view, it is outside the view, because the scroll view doesn't rolls down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot to fix apple solution to the problem I ended up writing some code myself after picturing the general idea behind apple code. I think apple code over complicate the problem and doesn't really work, by the way.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {

    self.firstResponder = textField;

    if (self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y + self.firstResponder.frame.size.height > self.view.bounds.size.height - (216 + 44)) {

        double fix = (self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y + self.firstResponder.frame.size.height) - (self.view.bounds.size.height - (216 + 44)) + 10;

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, -fix, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        self.view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    } else if (self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y + 10 < -self.view.frame.origin.y) {

        double fix =  -self.view.frame.origin.y - (-self.view.frame.origin.y - self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y) - 10;

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, -fix, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        self.view.frame = rect;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the toolbar height as well to the calculation,

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height + 44.0f, 0.0);
```

Also make,

```
aRect.size.height = aRect.size.height - keyboardSize.height - 44.0f;
```

Comment: The first lines solves 1. But the second one makes the UIScrollView goes down instead of going up.

Comment: Forgot to add. change this as well,  CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-10 + 44.0f)); If it is still not working remove the change with aRect.size.height = aRect.size.height - keyboardSize.height - 44.0f; part.

Comment: There's something wrong with both possibilities, the scroll view is going down. Man, I tried a lot of things.

Comment: In this line, you can change to this right? Why are you reducing keyboard height from the point to scroll? Check this. CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y);

Comment: Now it is working, but the text field is going all the way up like top 0.

Comment: That means you need to correct scrolltopoint part alone. If you want it exactly before toolbar, change it as CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.firstResponder.frame.origin.y -  (aRect.size.height - textfield.height));. This should move the textfield to near toolbar. Anyways if these are not working apple code is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same approach you have in your edit section but made a slight change to the if condition:

```
!CGRectContainsRect(aRect, self.firstResponder.frame)
```

This might help you fix issues where just the origin is above the keyboard, but the textfield is covered.